# Cannot edit css of a class with variable

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to get a line through  the li that i added when i click the li(like a grocery list).

```
$('document').ready(() => {
            let id = 1;

            $('.knop').click(() => {
                let boodschap = $('.tekst').val();
                let newli = `<li id="boodschap${id}"> ${boodschap}</li>`;
                $(".result").append(`${newli}`);
                id++;
            });

            $('ul').click(() => {
                let target = event.target.id;
                $(`${target}`).css({
                    "text-decoration": "line-through"
                });
                console.log(event.target.id);
            });
        });
```

I know the problem is in this part:

```
 $('ul').click(() => {
                let target = event.target.id;
                $(`${target}`).css({
                    "text-decoration": "line-through"
                });
```

I dont get a error in my console. so im stuck.
but when i hard code the part where i put my ${target} it works.
you cant use a variable in the css function?
is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you are missing the `#` from your ID selector. Just add it like this:

```js
$('ul').click(() => {
  let target = event.target.id;
  $(`#${target}`).css({
    "text-decoration": "line-through"
  });
});
```

Or just forget about the string ID selection and just select the element already being passed, like this:

```js
$('ul').click(() => {
  $(event.target).css({
    "text-decoration": "line-through"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have target.val in your top example but the specified code just hs target.

Which one do you have in your code?

Also should it be target.val()?

can you console log your target and target.val() to make sure its equal to what you are hard coding?

````
                let target = event.target.id;
console.log("my target", target)
console.log("target val", target.val())
                $(`${target}`).css({
                    "text-decoration": "line-through"
                });```
````

Comment: when i console log the let target i get the id "boodschap1" which is correct.
But when i fill it in as you did in your code with 
```$(`${target}`).css({"text-decoration": "line-through"});```
It does, nothing

Comment: I think you can just pass the variable without the string interpolation?
like $(target).css()
I think you'll need to add the # to it since it is an id so like:
$('#'+target)

Comment: same thing again. no error. but still does nothing..

Answer (score 0):

So you need to strikeout an `<li>` when it's clicked.

```
$('li').on('click', (evt)=>{
    let target = evt.target;
    $(target).css({'text-decoration': 'line-through'});
    console.log(evt.target.id);
}
```

The main problem with your code is that you store target `<li>`'s id, in a variable called target, rather than the target element itself. Misleading variable names can lead to confusion.

Comment: i can see where your coming from with the name. Ill change it. But still. the code doesnt work. the console log works. but the element doesnt get a strikeout when clicked
( i used the code you specified)